# Find difference between 2 python files

Tags: python, scripting, diff

The problem statement is:

Given 2 python files 'A.py' and 'B.py' (modified A.py), is there a way we can find out the:

1.Added methods

2.Removed methods

3.Modified methods : (a) Change in method prototype (b) Change in method content

Similarly for classes(changed/removed/modified) as well.

My Solution:

I was thinking if i could use a good diff tool, and find out the added/removed/modified lines, i can parse them to find out the required details.
I tried with git-diff but it gives line-wise diff. So if a method got shifted because some other method was added before that, it shows the method as deleted from the original file and added in the later file.

I saw 'meld' gives good diff between files which i could use easily, but i could not find a way to programmatically capture the output of meld.

Please provide any follow up on my solution, or any other solution for the problem

FYI: I want to automate this as there are many such files. Also, this has to be done on a linux box.

Answer (score 2):

Using

> `sdiff  File1 File2`

command in unix
 we can find difference between two files.

ex: if we change the add module and then compare two files
    the changes will appear with **>** symbol

```
def add(x,y):                           def add(x,y):
                                     >      print x,y
    return x+y                              return x+y

def subtract(x, y):                     def subtract(x, y):
    return x-y                              return x-y

def multiply(x, y):                     def multiply(x, y):
    return x*y                              return x*y
class MyFuncs:                          class MyFuncs:

  def divide(self,x, y):                      def divide(self,x, y):
      return x/y                              return x/y
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this would be to use a merge tool such as [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/)
This would enable you to see the two side by side and any differences would be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Git can do that, check out github its exactly what you look for

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) module:

```
from difflib import ndiff

with open("a.py") as a, open("b.py") as b:
    for dif in ndiff(a.readlines(),b.readlines()):
        print(dif)


- def foobar():

+ def foobar1():

?           +

-    a = 3

?        ^

+    a = 22

?        ^^

-    b = 4

+    b = 44

?        +

     print("foo")
```